# c programming synchronization between client and server

Tags: c, algorithm, networking, protocols, synchronous

I've been asked to implement a stop and wait file transfer program in c. I'm a noob so bear with me. The first part is for the client to send a file name to the server. If the client times out, it means the server never got the file name, resend the filename. However, if the server did get it and the status of whether the file exists or not gets lost going back to server, the client times out and resends the filename. Meanwhile the server, thinks everything's fine and proceeds to start sending the file contents. This is where I'm stuck. I don't want to send back another ack (essentially my 's' or 'e' is an ack that the server received it) because then I'm stuck with another possible file loss. I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the server from moving on until the client has received that status. I understand the algorithm of stop and wait on paper, but no clue how to implement this programmatically. Any clues? Thanks for any help.

Here's the piece of the client:

```
 FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  FD_SET(s, &readfds);
  //packetErrorSend randomly drops packets
  packetErrorSend(s, file, strlen(file)+1, 0);
  while(rv == 0)
  {
    tv.tv_sec = 4;
    rv = select(s+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (rv == -1) {
      perror("select"); // error occurred in select()
    } else if (rv == 0) {
      printf("Timeout occurred!  No data after 5 seconds.\n");
      packetErrorSend(s, file, strlen(file), 0);
    } else {
      status = recvx(s,buf,1);
    }
  }
//...check value of buf[0] to see if the file exists, if an 's' then start receiving file, if an 'e' print error and close
```

server piece:

```
  if ((bytes_transferred = recv(new_s,file,sizeof(file),0)) > 0)
    {
      fd = open(file,O_RDONLY);
      if(fd < 0)
      {
        perror("open");
        status[0] = 'e';
        packetErrorSend(new_s,status,1,0);
        close(new_s);
        exit(0);
      }
      status[0] = 's';
      packetErrorSend(new_s,status,1,0);

//...start sending file...
```

Comment: I removed select tag to make room for protocols and algorithm. Should probably remove the C tag as well.  This seems more of a protocol/alogorithms question than a C programming question.

Comment: thank you. I've spent way too long on this program (40+ hours). Almost had it done before I realized the problem of my acks getting lost.

Comment: Why don’t you rely on TCP which makes a reliable channel for you where no data can be lost? Is your task to simulate an unreliable channel?

Comment: yes. our first project was to just send packets usind send(). Now our professor wrote a function called packetErrorSend that replaces send and randomly drops packets. We have to use stop and wait to recover from those losses. However, he just notified me that we don't have to use stop and wait for the filename, just the file contents, which brings up another question. If the filename is lost, how would the client know to resend it? A few restrictions. We're not allowed to use send() and no select statements on the server side.

Comment: Nevermind on all that. He said don't use ARQ on filename, only file contents. I filename is lost, just close it and restart it physically.